# URL friendly title dash doesn't convert to null

Tags: php

i have the following code

```
$title = trim($tit);
$title = strtolower($tit);
$title = preg_replace("/\s/m", "_", $title);
$title = preg_replace("/\'/m", "_", $title);
$title = preg_replace("/[0-9+~!?@#;$%^&’*()\s]/", "", $title);
```

The problem arises when i have the following title

```
People are great - like or dislike?
```

And that converts to

```
people_are_great_�_like_or_dislike
```

I've tried many options like adding the dash in the final preg_replace in the code above. I tried to have a separate str_replace before the trim, after the preg_replaces etc. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: [What is your charset?](http://codepad.viper-7.com/dXwLLA) because that codepad works.

Comment: it is supposed to be utf8

Comment: [Yep even in this codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Pcf2NZ) i can't reproduce that issue. Can you verify that is **exactly** what the string looks like when it hits the server?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that in the db it is a dash, and then it is a dash in my Title variable but the friendlyTitle function above converts it with the � mark instead of the dash.

Comment: Please provide either the code to insert into the database, or the code you use to create the `$tit` varible and pass it to your function. Whichever is performed first, so we can get to the root of the problem.

Comment: $retdata = array(   
                    "title" => $row->title,
                    "friendlyTit" => friendlyURL($row->title)   
                ); the data which comes from the db is the same the above People are great – Like or dislike? and the friendlyTitle is with the diamond ? symbol.

Comment: Input is a function that checks for injection etc but it shouldn't affect the data since in the DB it's being add as a proper dash.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy by adding $title = str_replace("�", "", $title); to the bottom nothing works, but if I add $title = str_replace("�", "", $tit); (The actual title) then I get %20 for spaces and I get the dash. So i guess the problem is something with preg_replace.

Comment: $title = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z-ࠠ-��_\s]/", "", $title); this line of code to the bottom of the friendlyURL solves the problem but now I have two times '_' which are apparently the the ones around the �. I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30099/discussion-between-ohgodwhy-and-ando)